# Nonlinear Differential Equation with Pure Neumann Boundary

Tags: numerical-methods, heat-equation

Four governing equations concerning the reaction occurred in the porous electrode are
\begin{equation}
\nabla \cdot i_1 + \nabla \cdot i_2=0
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
i_2 = -\kappa \nabla \phi_2
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
i_1 = -\sigma \nabla \phi_1
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\nabla \cdot i_2 = a  i_{o}\biggl\{\exp\biggl(\frac{\alpha_{a} F}{RT}(\phi_1-\phi_2)\biggr) - \exp\biggl(-\frac{\alpha_{c} F}{RT}(\phi_1-\phi_2)\biggr) \biggr\}
\end{equation}

For large positive overpotential ($\phi_1-\phi_2$), the forth equation can be approximated as

\begin{equation}
\nabla \cdot i_2 = a  i_{o} \exp\biggl(\frac{\alpha_{a} F}{RT}(\phi_1-\phi_2)\biggr)
\end{equation}
The boundary conditions in one-dimensional case are
\begin{align}
i_2=-I_{app} \quad &\textrm{at} \quad x=0\\
i_1=0 \quad &\textrm{at} \quad x=0\\ 
i_2=0 \quad &\textrm{at} \quad x=L\\
i_1=-I_{app} \quad &\textrm{at} \quad x=L\\
\end{align}
Arbirary reference potential can be made as
\begin{align}
\phi_2=0 \quad &\textrm{at} \quad x=L\\
\end{align}
Also everywhere in the system we have
\begin{equation}
i_1 + i_2 = -I_{app}
\end{equation}

Now I try to solved the equations numerically by first rewrite the equation in terms of $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$
\begin{equation}
\frac{d^2\phi_1}{dx^2} = \frac{ai_{o} \exp\biggl(\frac{\alpha_{a} F}{RT}(\phi_1-\phi_2)\biggr)}{\sigma}\\
\frac{d^2\phi_2}{dx^2} = -\frac{ai_{o} \exp\biggl(\frac{\alpha_{a} F}{RT}(\phi_1-\phi_2)\biggr)}{\kappa}
\end{equation}
The boundary conditions above form only pure Neumann conditions for $\phi_1$ (through $i_1$), so I suppose there will be infinite solutions (if some conditions is achieved).

Now if I differentiate equation
\begin{equation}
\frac {di_2}{dx} = a  i_{o} \exp\biggl(\frac{\alpha_{a} F}{RT}(\phi_1-\phi_2)\biggr)
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\frac {d^2i_2}{dx^2} =\frac{\alpha_{a} F}{RT} \frac{d}{dx}(\phi_1-\phi_2) \cdot ai_{o} \exp\biggl(\frac{\alpha_{a} F}{RT}(\phi_1-\phi_2)\biggr)
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\frac {d^2i_2}{dx^2} =\frac {di_2}{dx} \frac{\alpha_{a} F}{RT} (\frac{I-i_2}{\sigma}-\frac{i_2}{\kappa})
\end{equation}
Suddenly it transforms to a well-posed second order equation in terms of $i_2$! How come? My problem is if I don't approximate the over potential term then I wouldn't be able to do this trick. I wonder whether this is a well-posed or an ill-posed problems.

Comment: If you integrate $$\frac{d^2\phi_1}{dx^2} = \frac{ai_0}{\sigma} \exp(A (\phi_1 - \phi_2))$$ over the $[0, L]$ interval you get the solvability condition
$$
0 = \int_0^L \frac{ai_0}{\sigma} \exp(A (\phi_1(x) - \phi_2(x))) dx
$$
which I assume gives only one possible solution

Comment: Thanks! But how do I imposed this extra condition? Thanks! Also, a finite difference book of mine written by Randall J. LeVeque says even if the solvability condition is satisfied, there will then be infinite solutions (as opposed to a singular problem). Do you recommend other good books on the field? Much appreciate!

Comment: Since the right hand side is a transcendent function, I'm trying to solve by Newton's method with these boundary conditions.

Comment: I add the difference of solvability condition to the source term of poisson equation, but using the Newton's method, the nonlinear exponential term has a hard time converging though.